# Check if first occurrence of string has an a tag before it

Tags: php, regex

I have created a script that goes through all my WordPress posts and replaces the first occurrence of a word with a link.

The problem I'm having is if I were to submit the form again the code will add double links.

I'm trying to work out a way to check if there is an A tag before the keyword/phrase.

The problem lies if the keyword exists in the URL replacement

for example,I replaced the word Tesco with a href of www.tesco.com - Tesco

I have a check that gets the position of the first character of my keyword/phrase and then minus 1 and checks if this is a > sign (if there was a tag before it there would be a > closing the open tag).

This works if the keyword/phrase doesn't exist in the URL but fails if it does exist in the URL.

is there a way to look for the first occurrence of a keyword/phrase and keep going back until I find the first space/tab and then check if there's an a tag between the space/tab and the start of the keyword?

I hope this makes sense.

thanks
Ian

Comment: Please add some code here which you have tried so far

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).